# How to resolve error Message: 'RegisterSod' is undefined when launching an App from on premise SharePoint 2013 server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I have created a sample App for SharePoint 2013 and deployed it successfully. When launching the app, I am getting the following error for every line of code calling RegisterSod

```
Message: 'RegisterSod' is undefined
Line: 14
Char: 1
Code: 0


<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("initstrings.js", "\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002f1033\u002finitstrings.js?rev=uNmvBiHdrBzcPQzXRpm\u00252FnQ\u00253D\u00253D");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">RegisterSod("strings.js", "\u002f_layouts\u002f15\u002f1033\u002fstrings.js?rev=cSu1pcWiRc999fyCNzJplg\u00253D\u00253D");RegisterSodDep("strings.js", "initstrings.js");</script>
```

Is there anyway this issue can be resolved?

Answer (score 7):

I know that it's old but I hope this will help somebody else having the problem:

This issue is most likely caused by not having a root site in the SharePoint Server.

Create a root site collection by going to the Central Administration –>Create Site Collection and when selecting the Web Site Address make sure you use ‘/’ as the site address which means that this will be the root site.

I did a blog post on this error [here](https://rakibism.wordpress.com/2015/06/29/sharepoint-2013-registersod-is-undefined/)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This script load the SP.Runtime.js and SP.js files by using the getScript function in jQuery. After downloading the file, your application has access to the JavaScript object model for SharePoint, including the function RegisterSod.

Please add this script to the page

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Get the URI decoded URLs.
    hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));

    // The js files are in a URL in the form:
    // web_url/_layouts/15/resource_file
    var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";

    // Load the js files and continue to
    // the execOperation function.
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "MicrosoftAjax.js",
        function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
                function () {
                    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", initContext);
                }
            );
        }
     );
});
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could include a little more information in your answer - for example, why does this fix the error? Why was the error even happening? Adding this will improve the quality of the answer and make it more helpful for other people who come looking for an answer to the same or a similar question.

Comment: Where to add this script ?

Comment: did you missed this function getQueryStringParameter() ?